# Can gitweb RSS feed show tags as well?

Tags: git, rss, gitweb

I use the gitweb RSS feed a lot for my remote repositories but it only shows me commits.

Is there a way to get creation of tag objects into the feed as well?

(I'm currently using 1.6.3.3 for the remote repositories.)

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as it is now.  Gitweb's feed (RSS and Atom) are just showing the history (log) of a given branch (default HEAD, i.e. current branch). You can sort tags by name using version sort, or by tagger date, but inherently tag doesn't have pointer to previous tag like commit has.

Still, you have sources, so you can extend gitweb (and hopefully provide patches to git mailing list, git@vger.kernel.org).

Comment: Hmmm... but I can list tags, and know when each tag was created, so should be able to merge this in with the commits.  You've given me something to think about. Cheers.